# topographic correction using GRASS 7.0 (**i.topo.corr**)

Tags: grass-gis

I would like to apply topographic correction using GRASS 7.0 (**i.topo.corr**). The imagery were already converted from DNs to Top-of-Atmosphere Radiances. When I apply the i.topo.corr command it runs normally without any error, but the result is a "white" image. I cannot see the bands, it seems that I am missing something. I applied topographic correction for Landat images from 1991 and 1979 and it worked perfectly using the same commands, but for Landsat image from 2003 and 2015 it does not work.

I'll explain what I did step by step.

The **illumination model** was created as follows:
i.topo.corr -i --overwrite output=2003_111.84_SRTM_illum basemap=SRTM_1s_mosaic@PERMANENT zenith=54.56122270 azimuth=78.49871615 method=minnaert

After the illumination model is created, i used it to correct the desired bands of the image:
i.topo.corr --overwrite input=13Jan2003_111.84_toar_B1@PERMANENT,13Jan2003_111.84_toar_B2@PERMANENT,13Jan2003_111.84_toar_B3@PERMANENT, output=tcor basemap=2003_111.84_SRTM_illum@PERMANENT zenith=54.56122270 azimuth=78.49871615 method=minnaert

Comment: What Landsat data did you use in each case? Different instruments (TM/ETM+/OLI) have different band combinations.

Comment: Hi reima, for Landsat MSS3, Landsat 5 TM and one Landsat OIL it worked fine and I got a really good result. But for Landsat another OLI and for Landsat 7 ETM+ it does not work. I used exactly the same commands. It runs normally without any error, but the result is a "white" image (white square for all bands).

Comment: Have you checked what the actual pixel values are? Also have you checked the input radiance data that it is correct and not containing  NA's or other possibly erroneous values? I don't know the GRASS-algorithm, per se ( I use R, ArcGIS and SAGA mainly), so I can't help with that one, but as said, the issue might relate to input data too.

Comment: I have checked the values. For example, I have the following values generated by i.landsat.toar (Reflectance of Landsat-7 ETM+ (method dos4)) for Band 1: Range of data:  Range of data: min = 0.01  max = 0.384689793990633 After applying i.topo.corr the values changed to Range of data:    min = -252.767458308413  max = 2928.43556843211.  I am a begginer user and any support will be welcome.

Comment: Hmm.. Your input values seems to be reflectance (not radiance), as it ranges between 0-1, but the latter seems more like radiance values and not reflectance. Which is of course erroneous, if this is the case. Sorry I can't help you with the grass-GIS stuff, as I do not have that. Can you perhaps try another program, such as R or SAGA GIS?

Comment: Have you checked the histograms of your images?? May I ask you, your images are from winter? Also if you can not see your image you can try "set color table,gray scale 0-255".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the color of the Landsat bands was set to white during the i.topo.corr process. When I set the color table for each band to gray I was able to see the bands.